# Why permissions to subfolders and files are not applied to new files?

Tags: permissions

In this question, I ask why some of my users do not have access to some files or subfolders.

[Why some users only have access to folder instead of all it's subfolders and files](https://superuser.com/questions/1538772/why-some-users-only-have-access-to-folder-instead-of-all-its-subfolders-and-fil)

That problem is fixed.

However, it doesn't apply to the new file.

The folder is D:\movies

I arranged that user Dian can access D:\movies and all things inside of this.

I deleted permissions and I readd permissions and it works.

With one catches

new folder doesn't work.

For example,

Say a new folder shows up in D:\movies called movie1.

Dian can access D:\movies\movie1 but not D:\movies\movie1\themovie.mp4 for example.

I want Dian to be able to access all folders and subfolders and files of **EVERYTHING** in D:\movies

Including files and folders created latter.

How to do so?

What's even more annoying is I cannot give access to Dian to the whole subfolder. I got a message that the subfolder already got permission inherited from its' parent.

It's parent means it's parent's folder's right?

[image]

So to reiterate

I set that Dian have access to all files and subfolders and all in D:\movies

A new folder show up called movie1 in D:\movies

Dian has access to D:\movies\movie1

However, Dian doesn't have access to D:\movies\movie1\file1.mp4 and D:\movies\movie1\file1.srt

Basically, Dian doesn't have access to all files and D:\movies\movie1\

Dian can see all subfolders.

I cannot give Dian access to all files in D:\movies\movie1 easily because there is no way to edit permission. I got to remove permission first and I can't do that because the permission is inherited from parent already.

What should I do so Dian can access **EVERYTHING** in D:\movies **ALL THE TIME**.

If I access Dian's account and try assign permission I often get failed to enumerate something. Let me check again.

Note: I can "solve" this problem by deleting Dian's permission from D:\movies and readding her permission. Of course, I do not want to keep doing that. Basically I want Dian to be able to access all the new folder in D:\movies without me having to do so again.

Here is the access control list

[image]

See no Dian. The folder itself have Dian as the one of the controller.

[image]

The folder D:\movies\movie1 has Dian as controller but that permission doesn't get passed down to the files below it.

Comment: What are the current settings of the ACL for the root folder?  Your last question was solved by recursively applying the permission you wanted to the folder, which means the screenshot in your previous question, likely just not represent the current truth.  There is not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: What is ACL? What do you mean by the root folder? I can "solve" this problem by deleting Dian's permission from D:\movies and readding her permission. Of course, I do not want to keep doing that.

Comment: Access Control List

Comment: what is access control list

Comment: Oh I see. Here is what happens. D:\movies\movies1 will have Dian as one of the controller. D:\movies\movies1\file1.mp4 will not have Dian as the controller

Comment: I am honestly now confused by your question.  I was just asking for the current ACL for the folder.  You should be giving access to user groups instead of specific users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106583/discussion-between-ramhound-and-user4951).